# Separator in Angular

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, algorithm, ionic-framework

I need to implement thousands separator for an input  in an Ionic app. I need to achieve this as user types them. I came with following implementation:

In Ts file:

```
 public amount:string;   // model

  format(){  

  this.amount=this.separator(this.amount)

  }

   separator(amount)
  {
    var num_parts = amount.split(".");
    num_parts[0] = num_parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return num_parts.join(".");
  }
```

In html:

```
 <ion-input [(ngModel)]="amount" (keyup)="format()"  placeholder="Text Input"></ion-input>
```

It works fine till number of digit remains 4 (in numeric part).It goes bad when I have more than 4 digit. Since it is called on  'keyup' in second pass it adds another ','  after second digit like this:

1,2,345

And this continues:  1,2,3,455

How Can I get this implemented right i.e. adding thousand separator as user types them. 
Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Your regex matches the position immediately after a group of 3 or 6 or 9... (etc) digits beginning not at the start of a word and not followed by another digit (therefore 4 and 5 or 7 or 8 adjacent digits will not be matched but 3 and 6 and 9 will ). Is this intended yes?

Comment: /\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ","), here {3}, limits what you are trying to do, I think you need to recheck the regex logic

Comment: @Atterson: Yes. It should put  ','  (comma)  after each 3 digit from right before decimal point until it reaches the last block  e.g. (1)  100,000      (2) 1,000,000

Comment: @Akhil: Does my above comment explains my goal here?

Comment: @Gautam, i am not an expert in regex, i hope it will do, {a,b} defines min of length 'a' and at max of 'b'. we can also use {a,} defines min 'a' length and infinite. :D

Answer (score 0):

There was problem in my implementation : I was not removing previously added comma. See the comment in following snippet

```
  separator(amount)
  {
    var num_parts = amount.split(".");
   num_parts[0]= num_parts[0].replace(/,/g , ""); // I was not removing previously added comma 
    num_parts[0] = num_parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return num_parts.join(".");
  }
```